# model hook failing browser reload

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a nested route that is setup as:

```
this.resource('actions', { path: '/actions' }, function() {
    this.route("action", {path: ':id'});
});
```

When I go to the `/actions` URL state it calls the model() of `ActionsIndexController` and successfully retrieves all of the records in "actions". If I reload at this point it *also* works fine, reloading all the records. The problem is when transitioning to a sub-route. When on the index page and transitioning to `/actions/[action-id]` the page loads as expected but when on that page if you reload the page -- which of course means the local state for Actions is gone -- it fails.

Here's the model hook in the `ActionsActionRoute`:

```
model: function(params) {
    console.log(params);
    return this.store.find('Action',params.id);
}
```

Interestingly in both use cases -- when you initially navigate to this URL *and* when you press reload in the browser -- it runs the model hook and the console statement gives a result of:

```
Object {id: "action-id", queryParams: Object}
```

The properties appear to be exactly the same yet in the reload scenario I gives the error:

> Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>       at DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.push (http://my.server.com/myApp/javascripts/vendor.js:71617:77)

Can anyone help me get me get over this gotcha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Router`, you specify the nested path as a `route` instead of a `resource`.

From the Ember guide:

`NOTE: You should use this.resource for URLs that represent a noun, and this.route for URLs     that represent adjectives or verbs modifying those nouns. For example, in the code sample above, when specifying URLs for posts (a noun), the route was defined with this.resource('posts'). However, when defining the new action (a verb), the route was defined with this.route('new').`

In your case, `/action/:id` represents a *resource*, not a *route* from the parent resource.  I suggest you change your code as follows:

```
this.resource('actions', { path: '/actions' }, function() {
    this.resource("action", {path: ':id'});
});
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, that sorted it. I need to go back to the docs and make sure this is black and white for me ... especially routes like "loading", "error", and even "index" sometimes are too much of an experiment each time and I'm sure the rules that govern are clear. Anyway thank god for the Inspector and helpful people like yourself. :)

Comment: Sure thing- you may also be interested in this post: http://darthdeus.github.io/blog/2013/02/01/ember-dot-js-router-and-template-naming-convention/